# Portable wchar_t in C++

Tags: c++, windows, portability, wchar-t, wstring

Is there a portable wchar_t in C++?  On Windows, its 2 bytes.  On everything else is 4 bytes.  I would like to use wstring in my application, but this will cause problems if I decide down the line to port it.

Comment: Would you need to share data between windows and other-OS installations (e.g. files, sockets)? If not, then I think you don't need to care about this issue (as long as you use sizeof instead of 2 or 4).

Comment: I plan to use a SQLite database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421530/is-endian-conversion-required-for-wchart-data#421603

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421530/is-endian-conversion-required-for-wchart-data for a related question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're dealing with use internal to the program, don't worry about it; a wchar_t in class A is the same as in class B.

If you're planning to transfer data between Windows and Linux/MacOSX versions, you've got more than wchar_t to worry about, and you need to come up with means to handle all the details.

You could define a type that you'll define to be four bytes everywhere, and implement your own strings, etc. (since most text handling in C++ is templated), but I don't know how well that would work for your needs.

Something like `typedef int my_char; typedef std::basic_string<my_char> my_string;`

Comment: You would need char_traits for that, and you can
't specialize std::char_traits<int> (per namespace std rules).

Comment: Also, you can simply use wchar_t/wstring internally. Externally, you use UTF-8 to bypass the endiannness mess. On I/O, convert between wchar_t and UTF-8 using template functions specialized on sizeof(wchar_t).

Comment: -1 Using my_char is bad idea. You can write string to stream you can't do anything with it

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by "portable wchar_t"? There is a `uint16_t` type that is 16bits wide everywhere, which is often available. But that of course doesn't make up a string yet. A string has to know of its encoding to make sense of functions like `length()`, `substring()` and so on (so it doesn't cut characters in the middle of a code point when using utf8 or 16). There are some unicode compatible string classes i know of that you can use. All can be used in commercial programs for free (the Qt one will be compatible with commercial programs for free in a couple of months, when Qt 4.5 is released).

[`ustring`](http://www.gtkmm.org/docs/glibmm-2.4/docs/reference/html/classGlib_1_1ustring.html) from the [`gtkmm`](http://www.gtkmm.org/) project. If you program with gtkmm or use glibmm, that should be the first choice, it uses `utf-8` internally. [`Qt`](http://qt.nokia.com/) also has a string class, called QString. It's encoded in `utf-16`. [`ICU`](http://www.icu-project.org/) is another project that creates portable unicode string classes, and has a `UnicodeString` class that internally seems to be encoded in utf-16, like Qt. Haven't used that one though.

Comment: Actually length(), substring() and Co. have no clue of the encoding, they just look at the coding unit size and work on that.

Comment: @Mihai, sure that's the case of std::string's function. But that's the reason it can't be used for utf8 etc.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: but the answer states "A string has to know of its encoding to make sense of functions like length(), substring()"
So no, it does not have to know. You can work in terms of code units without knowing the encoding, all you need is the size of the code unit.

Comment: @Mihai, if you use utf8, then code units have 8 bit size - but to calculate the length of a string, knowing that is not sufficient at all. You have to consider continuation bytes, and stuff. Otherwise you won't get the length of the string, but just the code unit count. Of course for fixed-length encodings like ASCII that won't matter, and knowing the code unit size is all that matters there.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "the length of a string".  If you're allocating memory or reporting disk usage, it *is* the number of code units that matters.  If you care about the number of *characters*, you do need to know the encoding.  And if you care about how many *columns* your strings takes up in a text terminal, that's yet another matter.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed C++0x standard will have `char16_t` and `char32_t` types.  Until then, you'll have to fall back on using integers for the non-`wchar_t` character type.

```
#if defined(__STDC_ISO_10646__)
    #define WCHAR_IS_UTF32
#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
    #define WCHAR_IS_UTF16
#endif

#if defined(__STDC_UTF_16__)
    typedef _Char16_t CHAR16;
#elif defined(WCHAR_IS_UTF16)
    typedef wchar_t CHAR16;
#else
    typedef uint16_t CHAR16;
#endif

#if defined(__STDC_UTF_32__)
    typedef _Char32_t CHAR32;
#elif defined(WCHAR_IS_UTF32)
    typedef wchar_t CHAR32;
#else
    typedef uint32_t CHAR32;
#endif
```

According to the standard, you'll need to specialize [`char_traits`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt05ch13s03.html) for the integer types.  But on Visual Studio 2005, I've gotten away with `std::basic_string<CHAR32>` with no special handling.

> I plan to use a SQLite database.

Then you'll need to use UTF-16, not `wchar_t`.

The SQLite API also has a UTF-8 version.  You may want to use that instead of dealing with the `wchar_t` differences.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion. Use UTF-8 and std::string. Wide strings would not bring you too much added value. As you anyway can't interpret wide character as letter as some characters crated from several unicode code points.

So use anywhere UTF-8 and use good library to deal with natural languages. Like for example Boost.Locale.

Bad idea: define something like typedef `uint32_t mychar;` is bad. As you can't use iostream with it, you can't create for example stringstream based in this character as you would not be able to write in it.

For example this would not work:

```
std::basic_ostringstream<unsigned> s;
ss << 10;
```

Would not create you a string.