# Conversion from basic_string to jstring

Tags: java, c++, string, java-native-interface

I'm using a `basic_string<wchar_t>` type and need to convert it into a jstring to pass through a JNI layer. I'm wondering what the best way to do that is. I have a function that can give me a `std::string` from my `basic_string<wchar_t>` type, so an answer to that would also be cool.

Cheers.

Comment: Note that `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` is typedef'ed to `std::wstring`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert jstring to wchar_t *](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042/how-do-i-convert-jstring-to-wchar-t)

Comment: Am trying to do the reverse of that, and am trying to see if I can avoid using a char* anywhere  in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870414/passing-double-byte-wchar-strings-from-c-to-java-via-jni

Answer (score 13):

You'll need to convert the std::basic_string into UTF-8.  Look into what your wstring -> string conversion does.

Sun has a JNI tutorial that shows how to convert a char* into a jstring (using some UTF conversion routines).  You could use your wstring->string, then pass in string.c_str() to the NewStringUTF function:

Untested Code:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL StringTest(JNIEnv *env) {
    const char* test = "something";
    return env->NewStringUTF(test);
}
```

Comment: That expects a **const char***.  What if I need to convert from **std::string**?

Comment: @Igor Use the std::string member .c_str().